# How to prevent profile urls from colliding with other routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

If I wanted user urls to look like

```
http://site.com/foobar
```

instead of

```
http://site.com/users/foobar
```

`foobar` would be the nickname of a user from the `nickname` column in the user model. How would I prevent users from registering top level routes? Like contact, about, logout, etc?

I can have a table of reserved names. So when a user registers a nickname, it would check against this table. But is there a more convenient approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('nickname') rescue nil)
  # forbid using desired nickname
else
  # nickname can be used -- no collisions with existing paths
end
```

**UPD:**

If any path seems to be recognized by the `recognize_path` then you've got something like:

```
get ':nick' => 'user#show'
```

at the end of your `routes.rb` which leads to the situation where any path will be routable. To fix this you have to use constraints. I'll show you an example:

```
# in routes.rb
class NickMustExistConstraint
    def self.matches?(req)
        req.original_url =~ %r[//.*?/(.*)] # finds jdoe in http://site.com/jdoe. You have to look at this regexp, but you got the idea.
        User.find_by_nick $1
    end
end
get ':nick' => 'users#show', constraints: NickMustExistConstraint
```

This way we put some dynamic into our routing system and if we've got a user with nick `jdoe` then route `/jdoe` will be recognized. If we haven't got a user with nick `rroe` than `/rroe` path will be unroutable.

**BUT** if I were you I would simply do two things:

```
# in User.rb
def to_param
  nick
end
# in routing.rb
resources :users, path: 'u'
```

And it'll give me the ability to get paths like a `/u/jdoe` (which is quite simple and totally comply with REST).

In this case make sure you are searching your users via `User.find_by_nick! params[:id]` (yeah, it's still `params[:id]` although contains a title, unfortunately).